# Вывод всех полей Entity без костылей

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

```
$card = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository("WebCodiumCatalogBundle:CreditCard")
        ->find($id);

    return new Response(json_encode(['data' => $card]), 200);
```

Почему такой очевидный код выводит `{"data":{}}`? И как вывести все поля Entity без костылей типа `$data = ['card_number' => $card->getCardNumber()];`?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ тут

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21230901/convert-single-entity-to-an-array

для этого нужно подключить `JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle`

после чего можно делать вот так:

```
return new JsonResponse($this->container->get('jms_serializer')->toArray(['success' => true, 'authUser' => $user]), 200);
```